# Parse JSON containing nested lists in Kotlin with Klaxon

Tags: json, kotlin, klaxon

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to parse list of lists in JSON:

```
data class Root (val lists: List<List<String>>)

val result = Klaxon().parse<Root>("""
{
    "lists": [["red", "green", "blue"]]
}
""")
```

But I get this runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

It seems that Klaxon can't quite figure out `List<List<String>>`.

I also need this to work in general for nested collections:

- `List<List<*>>`
- `Map<String, List<*>>`
- `List<Map<String, *>>`
- `Map<String, Map<String, *>>`

Comment: This is fixed in Klaxon 2.1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Klaxon 2.1.11.